# Query optimizing with Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

Here's my query:

- I have a `Personne` model that may have one or more travels through `PersonneTravel`.
- In `PersonneTravel`, the `travel` field is a foreign key to `TagWithValue`
- `s` is a 'start' date like "1954-05-01"
- `e` is a end date like "1999-05-01"
- `travel` is a string like "Paris, France"

So I'm doing a basic "search" to filter who did a travel and when.

Here's how I'm doing it and, because I'm a beginner with django, I'm pretty sure it could be optimized:

1. I retrieve all `pk` of `TagWithValue` that have a matching `value`
2. I retrieve all `pk` the `PersonneTravel` that have a travel matching those pk's before
3. I retrieve all `Personne` that matches the `PersonneTravel` pk's before

I'd like to return only one join like this (this is **not good sql** of course, but just to get the big idea):

```
SELECT ALL PersonneTravel PT
JOIN Personne P on P.personne_travel__pk = PT.pk
JOIN TagWithValue T
WHERE T.personne__pk = P.pk
AND T.value = "Paris, France"
AND T.tag = TYPE_GOOGLEMAPS
```

Is there a way to optimize this and do that with my following code?

```
q = Q()
if s:
    q = q & Q(date_start__gte=s)
if e:
    q = q & Q(date_end__lte=e)
retour = [a[0] for a in TagWithValue.objects.filter(
    type_tag__exact=BaseTag.TYPE_GOOGLEMAPS,
    value__exact=travel).values_list('pk')]
retour = PersonneTravel.objects.filter(Q(travel__in=retour) & q)\
    .values_list('personne__pk')
if len(retour):
    retour = Personne.objects.filter(pk__in=retour)
```

Comment: Please post your models.

Comment: It would have been if you could provide the model info. Assuming the structure, I have added the answer. Please `Accept` and `Upvote` my answer if it resolved your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `Q()` over here. Use `flat=True` with `values_list()` to get the list of values instead of list of type of values. This solution could be further simplified using [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in the `ForeignKey` column of the Django Model.

```
key = {}
if s:
    key['date_start__gte'] = s
if e:
    key['date_end__lte'] = e
key[travel__type_tag__exact] = BaseTag.TYPE_GOOGLEMAPS
key[travel__value__exact] = travel

retour = PersonneTravel.objects.filter(**key)\
    .values_list('personne__pk', flat=True)

if len(retour):
    retour = Personne.objects.filter(pk__id__in=retour)
```

Example with `related_name`: Let say `related_personne` is the related_name for `Personne` respectively in `PersonneTravel` model.

```
key = {}
key['related_personne__travel__type_tag__exact'] = BaseTag.TYPE_GOOGLEMAPS
key['related_personne__travel__value__exact'] = travel
if s:
    key['related_personne__date_start__gte'] = s
if e:
    key['related_personne__date_end__lte'] = e

retour = Personne.objects.filter(**key)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it without `Q-objects` by using django's `__` syntax:

```
query = Personne.objects.filter(personnetravel__travel__value__exact=travel,
                                personnetravel__travel__type_tag__exact=BaseTag.TYPE_GOOGLEMAPS) 

# because django querysets are lazy you can add the date filters now
if s:
    query = query.filter(personnetravel__date_start__gte=s)
if e:
    query = query.filter(personnetravel__date_end__lte=e)
```